# Struggling to solve this calculus problem.

Tags: calculus

Given the tangent to the curve $y=e^{2x}$ at the point where x = 1 and the tangent to the curve $y={1/2}e^{3-x}$ at the point (m,n) meet at a right angle, find the value of m and n.

I found y' of the first function to be $2e^{2x}$ and the second to be $-e^{3-x}/2$.  I then did (y-y1) = m(x-x1) to get the slope to be $2e^2$ and the tangent to be $y=m(x+2e^2) + 2e^{2x}$

I am stuck here unsure what to do and if I made any mistakes.

Comment: Slopes of two perpendicular lines meet equation $k_1 k_2=-1$

Answer (score 1):

HINT...The gradient of the second curve is perpendicular to $2e^2$ so it's $-\frac12e^{-2}$

so you just have to solve for $m$ the equation $$-\frac12 e^{3-m}=-\frac12e^{-2}$$